# Qt6 custom plugin cannot be loaded

Tags: c++, qt5, qmake, qt6, qtplugin

I am working on upgrade our lib from QT5,12 to Qt6.5

And I still build our plugins using Qmake.

After compile our plugin and install the plugin using bitrock, I got the error below:

[loading error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDA14.png)

The status is like this:

[plugins on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN8LS.png)

I should have 4 plugins, and NovosPackager seems working fine. NovosSimulate showed ok, but it does not appear on the QT toolbar. NovosUiDesigner have the loading error in the above picture. There should be a 4th plugin, which not even appear here. (Above are on Windows)

On Linux, 3 plugins working fine, NovosUiDesigner not appear:

[plugins on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hjqc.png)

If anyone could help on this?

Comment: Hi, check that the plugin is built against the correct Qt6 version and its 100% compatible. Also verify that the plugin's dependencies are given and the plugin is located in the correct directory.